# How to remove extra commas in string?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Can anyone please help me to remove extra commas from string and pass them to another string in well formatted to send an email from PowerShell.

```
$emails = "Abc@gmail.com,,,abc2@gmail.com,abc3@gmail.com,,"
```

I'm expecting string like below

```
$emailsTo = "Abc@gmail.com,abc2@gmail.com,abc3@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 $emails = ("Abc@gmail.com,,,abc2@gmail.com,abc3@gmail.com,," -split "," | where{$_ -ne ""}) -join ","
```

Comment: Hi Esperento57,

Comment: its adding comma in the end if $emails has space in the end $emails = ("Abc@gmail.com,,,abc2@gmail.com,abc3@gmail.com,,     " -split "," | where{$_ -ne ""}) -join ","

Comment: How to avoid comma for spaces as well ... sorry for multiple lines and questions

Comment: add a trim like it : ("Abc@gmail.com,,,abc2@gmail.com,abc3@gmail.com,, ".Trim() -split "," | where{$_ -ne ""}) -join ","

Comment: Thanks you @Esperento57... One more last question and it might be out of the scope for the main question since I cant post one more question so I'm asking you,  How can I compare two string values and extract not matched values from 2nd string($emailsTo here). $emails = "Abc@gmail.com,abc2@gmail.com,abc3@gmail.com"
$emailsTo = "Abc@gmail.com,hyz@xyz.com,abc3@gmail.com,manny@abc.com"  and Output should be "hyz@xyz.com,manny@abc.com" . I tried with $emailsTo | where {$_ -notcontains $emails} but its not working.

Comment: $emails = "Abc@gmail.com,abc2@gmail.com,abc3@gmail.com".Trim() 
$emailsTo = "Abc@gmail.com,hyz@xyz.com,abc3@gmail.com,manny@abc.com".Trim() 

$emailsarray=$emails -split "," | where{$_ -ne ""} 
$emailsToarray=$emailsTo -split "," | where{$_ -ne ""} 

$emailsToarray | where {$_ -notin $emailsarray}

Comment: thanks for helping me...  But it threw error ==>     You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
At line:1 char:28

Unexpected token 'notin' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:29

Unexpected token 'emailsarray' in expression or statement.

Comment: Sorry, its my mistake... Thanks a lot for your help..  StackOverflow is awesome !! this was my first question on StackOverflow

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`-replace`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) operator to collapse consecutive commas to a single one and remove leading/trailing commas from beginning and end of the string:

```
$emails   = 'Abc@gmail.com,,,abc2@gmail.com,abc3@gmail.com,,'
$emailsTo = $emails -replace ',+', ',' -replace '^,|,$'
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement the existing, helpful answers:

A more efficient and concise reformulation of [Esperento57's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40205153/45375):

```
> ',,Abc@gmail.com,,,abc2@gmail.com,abc3@gmail.com,,' -split ',' -ne '' -join ','
Abc@gmail.com,abc2@gmail.com,abc3@gmail.com
```

An alternative approach using the .NET Framework directly, via the `[string]` type's `.Split()` method with the `RemoveEmptyEntries` option:

```
> $emails = ',,Abc@gmail.com,,,abc2@gmail.com,abc3@gmail.com,,'
> $emails.Split(',', [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -join ','
Abc@gmail.com,abc2@gmail.com,abc3@gmail.com
```